# How to use Execute Immediate with INTO clause IN INFORMIX DATABASE

Tags: sql, dynamic, informix

I am trying to get count of all the tables using procedure in informix database.
But, I am getting error while fetching count using SELECT INTO statement using Dynamic
SQL.

Error - "Variable (v_count) has undefined value."

****Please let me know how to assign values to variable in "INFORMIX" using Dynamic SQL (SELECT count(*) INTO ****

```
CREATE PROCEDURE all_table_count_proc()
DEFINE v_table_name VARCHAR(70);
DEFINE v_count INT8;
DEFINE x VARCHAR(100);
DEFINE y VARCHAR(100);
DEFINE z VARCHAR(100);
LET x = 'SELECT count(*) INTO v_count ' ;
LET y = ' FROM ';
SELECT 
tabname
INTO
v_table_name
FROM
systables
WHERE
tabtype = 'T'
and tabid = 508;
LET z = x || y || v_table_name;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE z;
INSERT INTO table_count_details_tbl values(v_table_name,v_count);
END PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't.  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE does not take either input or output arguments.  You'd have to prepare a statement, declare a cursor, open, fetch, close the cursor, and release the cursor and statement.  You might be able to do without the prepared statement and the corresponding free. _[…Continued…]_

Comment: _[…Continuation…]_ (OTOH, after some time passed, I think you _will_ need the prepared statement as well as the cursor. A FOREACH loop should encapsulate the open/fetch/close logic.)  See the SQL reference manual on [Restrictions on Valid Statements (used with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statement-restrictions-valid-statements). And a MERGE statement could be used to insert or update a row in the `table_count_details_tbl` table.

Comment: Can you please give one example ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't use an INTO clause with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE does not take either input or output arguments. You'd have to prepare a statement, declare a cursor, open, fetch, close the cursor, and release the cursor and statement. AFAIK, you can't use FOREACH to encapsulate the OPEN, FETCH, CLOSE sequence, either.

See the SQL reference manual on [Restrictions on Valid Statements (used with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statement-restrictions-valid-statements).

This version of your code will do the trick for an arbitrary table name.  It has no error checking — so running the procedure on the same table name twice will generate an error, as will giving a non-existent table name, etc.  You'd probably want to use a `WHENEVER ERROR` clause to control error handling.  A [MERGE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-merge-statement) statement could be used to insert or update a row in the `table_count_details_tbl`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE table_count_proc(tabname VARCHAR(128))

    DEFINE tabrows BIGINT;
    DEFINE stmt VARCHAR(255);

    LET stmt = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || TRIM(tabname);

    PREPARE p FROM stmt;
    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR p;
    OPEN c;
    FETCH c INTO tabrows;
    INSERT INTO table_count_details_tbl VALUES(tabname, tabrows);
    CLOSE c;

    FREE c;
    FREE p;

END PROCEDURE;
```

This code 'knows' that the prepared SELECT statement will only select one row, so a single FETCH is sufficient.  In general, you'd need a loop to fetch all the rows to be returned.

Note that I use `BIGINT` rather than `INT8`.  For peculiar historical reasons, the `INT8` type (and the matching `SERIAL8` type) occupies 10 bytes (not 8 bytes) on disk.  Granted, the space wasted isn't huge, but don't use the `INT8` and `SERIAL8` types.  The `BIGINT` and `BIGSERIAL` types occupy 8 bytes on disk — always use them instead.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clear explanation.